# Unresolve Reference for MutableLiveData in Kotlin/IntelliJ?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin, androidx, android-sdk-tools

```
var data = MutableLiveData<Salt>()
```

This is the code as simple as that , i am trying to write and test my code in IntelliJ because is more faster and convinient for me .But i get an exception when trying to call mutable live data.

Unresolved Reference:MutableLive Data

and intelliJ doesn't seem to find de libraries by default , i looked online and it seems i have to get the android and gradle module on the project , i already installed all the modules gradle has by default on a community intellij but it is still unable to find it.
I could not install the android module, i clicked on install android sdk as it told me but it is stuck on this message

reparing "Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip

it never downloads , i downloaded the file by hand , if someone knows how to install it by hand, that would be great.
If there is a simpler way to use the MutableLiveDatatype , that would also help, i only want to use that on IntelliJ on a kotlin project is as simple as that.

Comment: That's because that is not the correct syntax in defining a variable: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-variables

Comment: And why are you using Intellij IDEA instead of the preferred Android Studio IDE for creating Android apps?

Comment: Because you shouldn't have a `:` there.

Comment: @Edric Because compile time is faster for me on intellij rather than  building the  app and using an emulator on Android Studio, so i test code there first the i move to android studio. But as it happens when you do things to fast , now i realize that there are better ways to do what i was trying to do and that i asked too fast. Still thank you very much everyone for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, that is not the correct syntax of declaring a variable in Kotlin.

Should be: `var data = MutableLiveData<Salt>()`.

Also, i'll **strongly** advice you use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio?authuser=1) which was designed specifically for Android development.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow maybe you in 2021 face this problem at old project using Live Data. You need to see at your build.gradle (for project) file and update the gradle classpath, Kotlin version, and another classpath if you had. So it will not give you an error anymore.

[image]